# Excel count if next cell value is diffrent

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have this data :

---

```
Kota Mataram   |    Mataram
Kota Mataram   |    Ampenan
Kota Mataram   |    Cakranegara
Kota Bima      |    Bima
Kota Bima      |    Asakota
Kota Bima      |    Rasanae Barat
Kab. Dompu     |    Dompu
Kab. Dompu     |    Hu'u
Kab. Dompu     |    Kempo
```

---

what i really want to produce is data which gives format :

---

```
1   |    Mataram
1   |    Ampenan
1   |    Cakranegara
2   |    Bima
2   |    Asakota
2   |    Rasanae Barat
3   |    Dompu
3   |    Hu'u
3   |    Kempo
```

---

So there is some kind of variable that recalculate (sum) if next cell value is diffrent. I am not excel expert and My logic is stop in COUNTIF. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the leftmost column starts at B1.  Put 1 in A1, and make another column starting at A2 containing

```
=IF(B1=B2,A1,A1+1)
```

Then fill down to make this column as long as the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `COUNTIF` if your data is sorted. You can use `IF`. Insert a column between the two you have above and assuming that the first cell is A1, then you only need to put `1` in the B1 cell, and in the below ones till the end, use:

```
=IF(A2=A1, B1, B1+1)
```

So, if the value in column A of the current row is the same as the above one, take B1, else add 1 to the previous count.